# Clojure can't find method JComboBox.addItemListener

Tags: swing, clojure

Hopefully this is just a stupid mistake, but I can't see it.

```
; OK
=> (filter (fn [x] (= "addItemListener" (.getName x))) (.getMethods javax.swing.JComboBox))
(#<Method public void javax.swing.JComboBox.addItemListener(java.awt.event.ItemListener)>)

; Error
=> (let [combobox (javax.swing.JComboBox. (java.util.Vector. ['a 'b 'c]))]
       (.addItemListener combobox
         (proxy [java.awt.event.ItemListener] []
           (itemStateChanged [item-event] (println (str "selection changed to " (.getSelectedItem combobox)))))
         combobox))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: addItemListener for class javax.swing.JComboBox (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Why can't clojure find the `addItemListener` method?

Comment: Same code in Seesaw, fwiw: (let [cb (combobox :model ['a 'b 'c])] (listen cb :selection (fn [_] (println (str "selection changed to " (selection cb)))) cb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the combobox a second time to the addItemListener method, you probably want to return it from the let form.

This should work:

```
(let [combobox (javax.swing.JComboBox. (java.util.Vector. ['a 'b 'c]))]
  (.addItemListener combobox
                    (proxy [java.awt.event.ItemListener] []
                      (itemStateChanged [item-event]
                        (println (str "selection changed to "
                                      (.getSelectedItem combobox))))))
  combobox)
```

Comment: Aagh, a parenthesis error, thanks! Are you sure about the `this` reference though? The examples in the cheatsheet (http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/proxy) don't use it, and I find my code works without it.

Comment: The documentation says so (http://clojure.org/java_interop#toc26). Maybe I don't understand it correctly, or maybe it's outdated?

Comment: Ah, missed the word "implicit". It's not passed to the function, it just magically appears in scope.